# Applovin returns error code 204 with test mode enabled

Tags: ios, ios8, applovin

I'm integrating Applovin into a cocos2d-x game and interstitial ads work just fine. I'm unable to receive any banners (most likely because of my location), though.

I went through the Applovin docs and found this:

> This error means “no fill” or that our server is unable to return an ad given the parameters/circumstancs of the ad request. We will never have 100% fill so it is important you can manage this error code correctly (see Best Practices for Handling 204s). If you are testing your app and need to see an ad to verify your integration, here are the likely causes of a 204 and their respective fixes:
>
> 1. **Advertiser demand is limited for your country/geo, app category, or phone characteristics. Fix: use the Test Toggle in the UI.**
> 2. ...

Source: http://support.applovin.com/support/solutions/articles/1000119815--define-kalerrorcodenofill-204

I suppose after enabling the test mode, that I should be able to receive test ads but I'm still getting 204s.

Comment: Do you know where they moved that page? Googling by some of quoted content like "Advertiser demand is limited for your country/geo" doesn't show any results.

Answer (score 2):

Once you turn on test mode it can take ~30 minutes to become effective, so you might just need to wait a bit. Also, it turns itself off after some amount of time (I think a few hours), so that could be the cause, too.

Comment: Nah, that wasn't the problem. I've tried that before even contacting Applovin's support team. I've tried different browsers, reseting both local and dns cache... Nothing. They had to enable it for me in the end.

Comment: Do you have AdBlock in your browser? Often times that will mess up the dashboards for ad networks since your browser is blocking scripts from those domains. You generally want to temporarily disable it when looking at an ad network dashboard.

Comment: Nope, never used AdBlock.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on an emulator and the ads were blank (error 204). When I tried on a physical device, the ads would come up.

Comment: After talking to the team at AppLovin, it looks like they disabled the effect of test mode from their SDKs - as some folks were pushing apps live with that flag turned on. The only way around the 204 (no ads filled) is to manually delete your app and do a fresh install. On Android, you'd just need to clear your app's data.

Comment: Can you mention where the flag for test ads is located?

Answer (score 0):

for Anyone who is doing this in 2023 , i spent 2 days on figuring this out with applovin max mediation with meta audience network , the problem lies in applovin sdk

what you need to do is

```
       implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:11.5.3'
```

set your placement in applovin

```
        IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#PLACEMENT_ID_HERE
        Example : IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#12040XXXXXXX07_120XXXXXXXXXX80
```

then you can see test ads in emulator also

Comment: Can you clarify you answer? Where do I set the placement?